# Close not called for a Response due to assert

Tags: java, jersey

I have the following test:

```
    @After
    public void tear_down() {
        remove_test_data();
    }

    private void remove_test_data() {
        delete_product("product1").close()
    }

    @Test
    public void test_crud() {
        Product product = product_factory("product1");

        Response response = post_product(product);
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(201));
        response.close();

        response = get_product(product);
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        Product gottenProduct = response.readEntity(ProductList.class);
        response.close();
    }

    private Response get_product(Product product) {
        return provider
                .target()
                .path(product.getName())
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get();

        return response;
    }
```

However, if the second assert fails (`assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200))`) then `response.close()` will not be called for this response. this means then that I get the following exception in my teardown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
```

what should I be doing to avoid this problem?

Comment: `try { ... } finally { response.close }` maybe? But personally i think if  a unit test errors, that signifies that something is wrong and you need to fix it. If the test succeeds you have no issue. Since the unit test should always succeed and it is just a unit-test I wouldn't be too worried about the exception being thrown. But try-finally should do the trick here.

Comment: yeah, I agree that the unit test shouldn't fail

Comment: @pandaadb This is a system test and I need to correctly teardown so as not to leave test data in the db.

Comment: then you would have to add `try ... finally` inside your test code to release connection if something fails during the test

Comment: I believe for that you would use maybe `@AfterClass` or `@After` which is executed by Junit and is meant to do cleanup operations (such as cleaning/deleting all leftover from the DB). Try/finally will work as well though

Comment: I would also suggest breaking your system tests into smaller ones: one for each of four basic operations

Comment: What about calling if(response!=null){response.close()} at the start of the teardown? Then I wont need try finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple try-finally usecase, for example:

```
try {

 // do work here

} finally { 
   if (response != null) response.close()
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to look into the `After` annotations provided by Junit for your test-management. These are usually used for cleanup operations.

As for your last question, you could try and close your response before doing anything else. However, read the docs for that:

```
/**
     * Close the underlying message entity input stream (if available and open)
     * as well as releases any other resources associated with the response
     * (e.g. {@link #bufferEntity() buffered message entity data}).
     * <p>
     * This operation is idempotent, i.e. it can be invoked multiple times with the
     * same effect which also means that calling the {@code close()} method on an
     * already closed message instance is legal and has no further effect.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * The {@code close()} method should be invoked on all instances that
     * contain an un-consumed entity input stream to ensure the resources associated
     * with the instance are properly cleaned-up and prevent potential memory leaks.
     * This is typical for client-side scenarios where application layer code
     * processes only the response headers and ignores the response entity.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Any attempts to manipulate (read, get, buffer) a message entity on a closed response
     * will result in an {@link IllegalStateException} being thrown.
     * </p>
     *
     * @throws ProcessingException if there is an error closing the response.
     * @since 2.0
     */
```

This means, that if you close the response, you might run into different errors down the line. For example, your provided test looks like such:

```
        response = get_product(product);
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        Product gottenProduct = response.readEntity(ProductList.class);
        response.close();
```

If you closed your response before reading the Entity, the entity stream would have been closed and this would throw an exception for you.

So, I think, if you want to properly close it in code not using JUnit annotations, then you should use `try-finally`.